# Qt5 QWidget :hover effect delay

Tags: c++, css, qt, visual-c++, qt5

I am trying to create any kind of `:hover` effect on my `QWidget` with the following CSS:

```
QWidget.mis--MyButton {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background:  white;
    /*cursor: pointer;*/
    font-family: Calibri;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(218, 218, 218); /*#007FEB;*/

    padding: 1px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

QWidget.mis--MyButton:hover 
{
    border: 2px solid #007FEB; /*#007FEB;*/
}
```

However, there is a slight delay of 2-3 seconds from the time the mouse enters the widget until the time the effect appears.

Here's the screencast of what happens:

https://youtu.be/aNfEKabut-A

For painting I use the following code:

```
void MyButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{ 
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);   
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);

}
```

Even when I try to get rid of the CSS, i.e. don't load the CSS whatsoever, and just try to have any effect and use Qt's style, for example, this way:

```
style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_PanelButtonBevel, &opt, &p, this);
```

and just turn off the CSS, I still get the same delay.

Here's a screencast of the same effect, without the CSS loaded and with `QStyle::PE_PanelButtonBevel` option selected in the `paintEvent`:

https://youtu.be/kT10zdepsGk

Computer is rather strong, Ryzen 7 on Windows 10, and I am using VC++ 2017, so it shouldn't be related to anything like that.

If you need more code, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Did you try profiling your code? 2) Why you are not using Qt MVC or QML or Qt Graphic Scenes?

Comment: Hm, mosty because I did not know about it (QML)  :-)  I will check it out and in a few days see if it actually made anything better for me. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using jQuery? Seriously don't listen to that guy. There is no problem with your code. I cannot reproduce the issue using MinGW on a much older windows 7 machine. Also this is just standard code. Are you maybe running the program inside the debugger? The CDB debugger integration in Qt Creator can be painfully slow sometimes.

Comment: "Computer is rather strong, Ryzen 7 on Windows 10, and I am using VC++ 2017, so it shouldn't be related to anything like that." It does not matter how strong your computer is, if your CPU is at 100%. What is your CPU occupation level ? Have you built in Release or Debug? Do you have a debugger attached?

Comment: @SteakOverflow  It is not preoccupied, maybe I listen to music in the background while I work :-) , and of course I wouldn't post it here if the CPU was spiking. All other programs based on Qt on my system (including the Qt Creator, and Skype for example) work just fine

Comment: @DushanSavich Can you answer about the debug build and the debugger? And if you have seen difference in release mode. For the CPU spiking, note that on a 4 core cpu, 25% occupation is all it takes to slow down a single threaded application.

Comment: can we see a live exemple?

Comment: @Stephen  It's actually a part of a rather big project.  I am not really sure if I would be able to separate it easily here

Comment: Hi! Have you try to change your widget style just for it? I mean, using qtCreator, editing your button using StyleSheet just for this MyButton, and tags of QPushButton{} and QPushButton::hover{}.

Comment: @Dmitry Sazonov Hey bud! I've just tried placing everything in QML / Qt Quick and for some reason everything is indeed faster. If you can put it in an answer, I will gladly give you my 50 bounty fake internet points :-) Thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: @DushanSavich i dont care about points :), it is good that you solved your issue. Anyway, you may accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fast animations with large amont of items it is recommended to use QtQuick/QML scene.

QSS is slow, because it requires a lot of recalculations and made on CPU. QGraphicsScene works faster, but again - it is CPU and requires a lot of hand-made visualization code.